# Do while not working as excepted, Loop never stop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, do-while

I am trying to automaticly send to printer all .pdf file from a folder.

Here is the code I am trying

```vb
Option Explicit

Declare Function apiShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
    ByVal hwnd As Long, _
    ByVal lpOperation As String, _
    ByVal lpFile As String, _
    ByVal lpParameters As String, _
    ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
    ByVal nShowCmd As Long) _
    As Long

Public Sub PrintFile(ByVal strPathAndFilename As String)

    Call apiShellExecute(Application.hwnd, "print", strPathAndFilename, vbNullString, vbNullString, 0)

End Sub

Sub Test()

Dim filepath As String
Dim currfile As String
Dim wrdApps As Object
Dim wrdDoc As Object

Set wrdApps = CreateObject("Word.Application")
filepath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\AIMPRIMER\"
currfile = Dir(filepath & "*.PDF")

Do While currfile <> ""

    PrintFile (filepath + currfile)

    currfile = Dir()
Loop

End Sub
```

`Do While` Is used to browse all pdf file from the folder

`PrintFile (filepath + currfile)` Must send the current file to printer.

I except this to print all .pdf once but actually the do while loop isn't working as accepted, the do while loop is looping and never stop.

I tried : `Debug.Print filepath + currfile` here i got all .PDF 's path once, But this path isn't send once to the printer.

So I don't understand why `Debug.Print filepath + currfile` is working nicely and when I use `PrintFile (filepath + currfile)` the printer print and never stop printing...

Comment: Is `PrintFile` by any chance using a `Dir`-command?

Comment: @FunThomas When I delete the loop and put just `PrintFile(Path)` It is working nicely

Comment: That wasn't my question: If `PrintFile` is issuing a `Dir`-command (for example to check if the file exists before printing), it will start a new Dir-Loop

Comment: @FunThomas The PrintFile is not using a `Dir` command. I have put the `Sub PrintFile` ìnto my post issue.

Comment: The `PrintFile` itself is calling another function. What happens if you delete `PrintFile()` from that loop and replace it by `Debug.Print currFile`?

Comment: @JohnColeman It display all my **.pdf** directories, should I try with the `Debug.Print Path` out of the loop ? I think it will just display the first **.pdf** file path

Comment: If removing `PrintFile (filepath + currfile)` prevents an infinite loop, then it is the problem. As a side effect it must be resetting `Dir`. If it is an external API, you might not be able to determine why. What you could do is loop through once, saving the names to a collection, then have another loop which processes this collection of names.

Comment: ***the do while loop is looping and never stop.*** Do you mean the documents are printed multiple times? Only the first one?

Comment: @VincentG It dépends I had the both case (I tried 2 time)

Comment: Would it be better to loop through and populate the files into an Array or Dictionary, and then loop through that to print?

Comment: @JohnColeman Thanks i did it with collection, Now it is nicely working. Thanks for your time ! How do  I set this Issue as solved, should I add the answer myself ?

Comment: Glad it worked. @FunThomas had the crucial idea that the problem was likely that `PrintFile` was somehow interfering with `Dir`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the API call is throwing off the `Dir`, although I'm not able to replicate this problem (it seems my initial attempt did produce the infinite loop, but I'm not able to reproduce it a second time...). Best to build the list of files *first*.

```
Dim filepath$, currfile$, item
Dim files As New Collection

filepath = "C:\debug\"
currfile = Dir(filepath & "*.pdf")
' build a list of files to be printed later
Do While currfile <> ""
    files.Add filepath + currfile
    currfile = Dir()
Loop
' print each file in the list we created in previous loop
For Each item In files
    PrintFile currfile
Next
```